# Issue while addinng Postgresq as database for one Node in Enterprise Cordapp

Tags: corda

I was working on trial version of corda enterprise edition ( cordapp-example-release-enterpise-v3 ). I tried to change one Node's database from H2 to PostgreSQL by using code shown below

```
node {
        dataSourceProperties = {
        dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
        dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
        dataSource.user = test
        dataSource.password = test123
    }
    database = {
        transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
    }
    name "O=PartyC,L=Paris,C=FR"
    p2pPort 10013
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10014")
        adminAddress("localhost:10054")
    }
    webPort 10015
    cordapps = ["$corda_release_group:corda-finance:$corda_release_version"]
    rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}
```

while start buid using gradlew clean build am getting an error like `Could not set unknown property 'dataSourceProperties' for object of type net.corda.plugins.Node.` can somebody help me with this. also if I am using IntelliJ to Run the code then how do I edit NodeDriver kt file?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataSourceProperties` belong to `node.conf` and not `deployNodes` task and hence it won't work, as `cordform` doesn't know anything about `dataSourceProperties`, you see the error `Could not set unknown property`. You can use `extraConfig` to make this work. However, I'd recommend to make these changes in the `node.conf` and use bootstrapper tool for bootstrapping. One example to use `extraConfig` is below.

eg:

```
node {
....

    extraConfig = [
                    dataSourceProperties : [
                            'dataSourceClassName' : "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource",
                            '"dataSource.url"' : "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9105/persistence;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;WRITE_DELAY=100;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE;",
                            '"dataSource.user"' : "sa",
                            '"dataSource.password"' : ""
                    ],
                    database : ["transactionIsolationLevel" :"READ_COMMITTED"]
             ]

}
```